# ReactJS - Protected routes based on an api call response

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, local-storage

I am trying to implement protected routes using an API endpoint, but the response is slower compared to rendering.
As a result, I have the correct data in my localStorage but react never uses them on time.

I am using localStorage to save my API auth response with an initial state and a dispatcher to update my state across the app.

What I have done right from the top:

**initialState:**

```
export default {
  auth: {}
};
```

**App.js**

```
const App = () => {
  const [data, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    asyncStorage.getItem('data').then((storage) => {
      dispatch({ type: "PERSIST_DATA", payload: JSON.parse(storage) });
    });
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    asyncStorage.setItem('data', JSON.stringify(data));
  }, [data]);
  
  return <Router data={data} dispatch={dispatch} />;
};
```

**Router.js**

```
export default function Router({data, dispatch}) {
  
  return (
    <ProvideAuth data={data} dispatch={dispatch}>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
            <PrivateRoute path="/" data={data} dispatch={dispatch}>
              <Home data={data} dispatch={dispatch} />
            </PrivateRoute>
            <Route path="/sign-in" render={() => <Signin data={data} dispatch={dispatch} /> } />
          </Switch>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </ProvideAuth>
  )

} 

function PrivateRoute({ children, ...rest }) {
  const auth = useAuth()
  
  return (
    <Route {...rest} render={({ location }) =>
        auth.loggedIn ? (children) :
        (<Redirect to={{ pathname: '/sign-in', state: { from: location } }} />)
      }
    />
  )
}
```

**Auth.js**

```
const authContext = createContext();

export function ProvideAuth({ children, data, dispatch }) {
  const auth = useProvideAuth(data, dispatch)
  return <authContext.Provider value={auth}> { children } </authContext.Provider>
}

export const useAuth = () => useContext(authContext);

function useProvideAuth(data, dispatch) {
  const [loggedIn, setLoggedIn] = useState(null);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    auth
      .me(dispatch)
      .then(() => {
        setLoggedIn(true);
      })
      .catch(() => {
        setLoggedIn(false)
      });
  }, [])

  return {
    loggedIn
  }

}
```

**auth.me**

```
export function me(dispatch) {
  return api
    .me()
    .then((response) => {
      dispatch({ type: "UPDATE_AUTH", payload: response });
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      throw error;
    });
}
```

I feel I'm almost there but I am probably missing something obvious.

Answer (score 0):

No 1: I believe, your second useEffect in App.js might keeps running almost every seconds since there is no dependency array specified, this may affect the update you are expecting, since the component keeps mounting

No 2: I have no idea what the auth.me(dispatch) in Auth.js does, so it might be difficult to infere

Comment: Second useEffect runs only once. I can't find another way of keeping data in storage after a browser refresh let's say. auth.me requests from the API and updates the localStorage state with an email.

Comment: If that is the case, why not console.log(auth.loggedIn) to see if it is false or true first.
You can confirm if your state is truly updating to to true

Comment: It does, and as I mentioned the problem is that it does after the page is redirected to Sign in.

Comment: I can't really give an optimum solution, since I can't see the working working code But i think this should work 
If you are getting auth.loggedin to be true after redirecting to sign in page, I think you just need to add a useEffect in Sign In page that checks if auth.logged in is true and redirects to the homepage

Comment: If I just put the same logic behind SignIn component, it will redirect on the sign in form after each navigation click. I'm surprised that there's no common way to do this.

Comment: I am sure something is not right somewhere. Without access to the full working code, it will be difficult to fix the bug